# Change number of decimal digits in all tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal

I'm not much experienced in SQL and I need to modify my tables as follows but cannot work out how to do so.

I have a MySQL database with multiple tables where some of the columns have type e.g. DECIMAL(17, 2) and I need to change the type to have at least 4 decimal places as effectively as possible.

Can someone help me with this please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` is the way to go. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do it via the `ALTER` that @Barranka suggests.  However, there are two enhancements:

- MODIFY all the COLUMNs in a single table in a single ALTER; this will run faster.
- You *could* write a Stored Procedure to read information_schema.COLUMNS to discover which tables have DECIMAL(xx,2) and create the ALTERs for you.

But, why do you want 4 decimal places?  If you are that loosy-goosy about the precision of the numbers, perhaps FLOAT or DOUBLE would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column definitions with `ALTER TABLE`. Example:

```
alter table your_table
    modify column a_number decimal(19,4);
```

In this example, I'm enhancing the column `a_number` so it holds now a number of length 19 with 4 decimal places. You need to increase the length of the column, not just the decimal places, because if you have numbers with 17 digits (including 2 decimals), you may loose some values if you don't increase the length.

Check [the reference manual for `ALTER TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html).